# How to connect to an imap server using an ssl certificate in php?

Tags: php, ssl-certificate, imap

I need to connect to a mail server which has a an ssl certificate. I am able to connect to the server using the following code:

```
imap_open ("{localhost:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}", "user_id", "password");
```

But this would ignore or skip validation of the certificate. How can i enable validation of the certificate?

Using the following code as per the php manual gives me an invalid certificate error.

```
imap_open ("{localhost:993/imap/ssl}", "user_id", "password");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a self signed certificate?  If you are then the validation would fail.  If you are not using a self signed certificate make sure it is configured properly for your host/domain.

Comment: I am using a self signed certificate since only my application is "suppposed" to access the mail server. Users access their mail through the application.

If i use `novalidate-cert` would the communication between mail server and application be encrpted??

Is there a way to validate a self-signed certificate??

Comment: Since a self signed certificate does not have a CA (certification authority), you would need skip validation.  Even if you skip validation, the connection will still be encrypted.